# Why div does not re size after keypad down?

Tags: cordova

When keypad closed, but the div/page does not re size.Its show empty space with size of keypad. What I do. Kindly solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this,

Replace your html meta tag with this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

Also put this in your config.xml

```
<preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="false" />
```

Hope this may help you